# monogame system reference not found

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2017, monogame

I just installed the monogame (v3.7), created a new project (in VS2017) for windows, tried to run it, and this error popped up:

[image: ERROR]

I can't add even System reference manualy, and I cant find the answer to this anywhere. Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed what happened. I didn't have any target framework set for this project for some odd reason. So instead of deleting this question, I hope this answer helps.

**To fix this**, go to solution explorer, right cilck your project, proerties, in Application tab select the Target framework.

I selected the latest I had (.NET Framework 4.6.1). I will make a guess that the latest one should work fine